# How to create table in the local Dynamodb?

Tags: c#, amazon-dynamodb

I work in Windows 10. I run the docker aaronshaf/dynamodb-admin, ok.
It contains DynamoDb and web ui.
My goal is: to create c# application which works with dynamodb.
How can I create a table in the Dynamodb via web ui?
Or via c# application?

Comment: It's not an answer to your question, but in my experience, running dynamo locally is a complete pain and waste of time. You might have better luck creating a table on aws and adding a policy to your local programmatic role to connect. The SDK will do the heavy lifting, just grant the correct permissions and away you go...

Comment: Hi Richard, thank you. your opinion makes sense.  But the real AWS is not free and I want to start development to check how it works and so on. That's why I run DynamoDB docker.

Comment: If it's a new account you'll likely get some sort of free tier. Besides, Dynamo can be set to On Demand, so it'll only cost you what you use. In the case of running some tables for learning purposes, that'll likely amount to just a few cents per month, literally.

Comment: To elaborate, if you were to perform 10k reads and 10k writes in a month, and store 0.5 GB, that'd cost you $0.13.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with `aaronshaf/dynamodb-admin`, but I've been able to set up  `dynamodb-local` to work very well for the entire dev/test lifecycle.

1. In the terminal run `docker run -p 8000:8000 amazon/dynamodb-local -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb -inMemory` to run dynamodb-local image on localhost:8000
2. Run any command you need via aws-cli but specify the local endpoint. Ex.

```
aws dynamodb create-table \
    --table-name YourTableName \
    --attribute-definitions \
        AttributeName=YourPK,AttributeType=S \
        AttributeName=YourSK,AttributeType=S \
    --key-schema AttributeName=YourPK,KeyType=HASH AttributeName=YourSK,KeyType=RANGE \
    --provisioned-throughput ReadCapacityUnits=1,WriteCapacityUnits=1 \
    --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000
```

3. To run your app locally with DynamoDb-Local, configure your DynamoDB SDK client's endpoint to `http://localhost:8000`.